# What is a "USC resume"?

Tags: job-search, resume, terminology

I saw a job posting from a company called Radiant Digital. The title of the position is "Senior Cloud Engineer- Need USC resumes only". Now, I am pretty tech savvy, but I can't find any abbreviation for USC besides University of Southern California that seems to fit. Does anyone know what a USC resume is? Or are they specifically looking for graduates from a specific school? Could they mean U. S. Citizen? I've never seen it abbreviated like that before.

Comment: Beginning in the 1960s, the US government has passed a number of laws / issued a number of executive orders that for the most part make it illegal to discriminate based on citizenship status. There is an exclusion: The  US government allows itself to discriminate based on citizenship status, and it can require its contractors to do so.

Comment: USC is a really lazy way of communicating something important like United States Citizen. There is zero benefit to the acronym unless you were trying to stay within a tweet limit. Any job I've seen posted always spells out the important stuff like Green Card, citizenship, and visa requirements. Why leave it to chance, is this the type of employer you'd want to work for?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus If the style of the HR department is already a red flag, I'm not sure how many companies would survive the vetting process.

Comment: @Mast Especially since the company appears to be using headhunters, not in-house recruiters.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I haven't seen that either, but my guess is you are correct and it stands for *United States Citizen*.  That is also a rather crappy way to say *no sort of sponsorship/visa* is being offered.

Certain positions require US citizenship and can not be offered to foreign nationals regardless of their sponsorship or visa needs. (*Updated from the comments*)

Comment: The company has multiple locations in both India and the US, and also deals with US government contracts.  So they should know how to  clearly state requirements.

Comment: I think you are correct, and the answer hit me as I was getting ready to post. I almost didn't, but I thought maybe it was something I was totally overlooking. Thanks.

Comment: The rule is much stricter than just _"no sort of sponsorship/visa"_.  It mandates full US Citizenship.  As @DavidHammen has pointed out, this is an illegal restriction _except_ if it is a US Government job or it is a government contractor and the government has dictated that only citizens can apply.  In many contexts, even US _dual-citizens_ can be rejected (since they are generally excluded from getting US security clearance).  I'm not sure what happens for positions where a company offers "tech support from US citizens only" as a feature for US Government (and contractor) customers.

Answer (score 20):

[USC means US citizen as opposed to GC which means Green card holder.](https://www.avvo.com/legal-answers/whats-the-difference-between-a-gc-holder-and-usc---1083176.html)

Comment: To add: many projects involving USG(US Government) contracts require that people working on them to be US citizens.

Answer (score 13):

This has been posted in a couple of comments but it's worth it to go into an answer:

USC means US citizen.

This is almost certainly a job on a government contract, based on the wording and also the location (Virginia).

Many government contracts specify that all staff on the contract must be US citizens. Depending on the exact contract, it may be [mandated by law](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/48/3052.204-71). (The law makes it sound like there may be some possibility for an exemption, but that's only if they absolutely cannot find a US citizen to do the same work. For a cloud engineer, however senior, there is no way they can't find a US citizen so there is no hope of exemption. The exemption might apply for some world class researchers or something, or maybe someone who is defecting from another country and has personal knowledge that is valuable.)

Specifically, it's nothing to do with anyone's willingness to sponsor someone for a visa or pay the costs of a visa or anything like that. If the client (government) says that they will only take people meeting X requirement on the contract, then the company only has any use for people meeting X requirement.

The federal contracting world can feel pretty small at times, especially in the capital region and coastal military cities (Norfolk), with a lot of the same people moving between the same contracts, so I think they've got a bit casual about assuming that everyone who would be qualified would already be familiar with this terminology.

The only surprise here is that they haven't mentioned some required clearance level. There are sensitive-but-unsecured positions, but increasingly everything is just becoming secured, and usually such positions would mention at least "ability to get XYZ clearance".

Comment: And, as I noted above, _"ability to get XYZ clearance"_ generally excludes US _dual citizens_ (like, for example, me).

Comment: Searched the company name, “Radiant has supported QATS and Application Development projects for Homeland Security.”, came up as the first result.  I would agree with your conclusion.  As for the reason the job posting doesn’t indicate a security clearance is required, it probably did, and the author didn’t mention it.

Comment: @Donald I found the job posting (or at least, same company, same title with USC only), it didn't mention a clearance. So either they're getting really sloppy, or it's not actually secured. Or, I guess, they're willing to take a chance on being able to get a clearance for someone--which is possible, given how hard it is to hire people right now (most people seem to be sitting tight because pandemic, or at least my team is even more short staffed than usual and having a hard time filling those positions).

Comment: @user3067860 - It’s hard to do my job when “remote work” isn’t even in the cards with the networks I access.  My team has had an opening for 4 months now and it typically would have been filled within 30 days.

Comment: @Donald We are 100% remote right now and still have trouble finding people. (Although some people who were clearly thinking about leaving have stayed, because...also pandemic.) There's more going on in my contract than just that, but definitely even more desperation than usual in hiring.